# Retrieve existing hbase table's schema

Tags: c#, java, hbase, thrift

I want to know is it possible to retrieve existing hbase table's schema ?

I want to know what's column families' name and so on.

if any .net or java code , I will really appreciate to post for me.

Comment: What have you tried? It doesn't sound like your looking to know if it is possible, rather it sounds like you are looking for someone to code it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You only need to invoke [HBaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor](http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/HBaseAdmin.html#getTableDescriptor%28byte%5b%5d%29):

```
HBaseAdmin hbaseAdmin = new HBaseAdmin(config);
HTableDescriptor tableDescriptor = hbaseAdmin.getTableDescriptor(tableName)
```

The tableDescriptor object will contain all information about the table (families, etc).